# Ninja Form does not submit

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I must have filled this form out at least 5 times and I am seeing a "no Submissions Found" message in the submissions tab. Any ideas why?

http://gdh.kailikameoka.com/volunteer/

Comment: I don't think this is a self-included question or related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Although we can simulate the error, in this case, it would be necessary to be inside of your wordpress to check both app and smtp configuration to locate the source.

So look at your SMTP configuration part, see if it agrees with the indicated smtp server/port for your host/plugin and if still does not respond, 
use any of the apps for SMTP configuration recommended by them in this webpage: https://ninjaforms.com/ninja-forms-email-not-working/

Most issues with forms in wordpress are on misconfiguration in smtp server and plugins.

Good luck there!

Comment: This morning, i noticed that the form had sent me emails but they still don't appear in the plugin. Is this still an SMTP issue? Where are the SMTP configurations for Wordpress and GoDaddy?

Comment: Hi @KailiKameoka ! If it is sending but in the plugin is not showing, then this means your SMTP configuration is ok, which leads us to your plugin, it can be misconfigured or outdated, have you try o re-install it ?  

If you want to check your SMTP configuration on your wordpress, go for the " Settings " part inside your wordpress to see it, this link will help you if you need it: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/use-smtp/